# Docker connection refused to host service on port 9037

Tags: java, docker

I'm running a single docker container locally - it's running a spring boot java microservice.
That service must connect to a windows hosted server at 9037. I'm getting this exception stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.companyname.security.wam.util.WebClientException: Error executing request http://localhost:9037/services/policySvc/policy/All
    at com.companyname.security.wam.util.WebClient.createAndCallHttpPost(WebClient.java:110)
    at com.companyname.security.wam.util.WebClient.callPost(WebClient.java:61)
    at com.companyname.security.wam.policy.client.ZoneAndPolicyClient.getAllPolicies(ZoneAndPolicyClient.java:37)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9037 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.companyname.security.wam.util.WebClient.createAndCallHttpPost(WebClient.java:105)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
     26 common frames omitted
```

This works fine when run directly from Intellij.